# Huge JOIN result set crashing server

Tags: php, mysql

I have a really large result set that comprises nearly 2 GB of product data spread across several tables with about 500,000 records in total per table. I need to process each record for export to a set of files.

The following will crash the server as it tries to hold the result set, so I had to switch to just creating a query to fetch only the primary id of each record that matches the query results, then perform a 2nd query on each primary id to get that individual product. This is horribly inefficient and database intensive as a consequence of all those secondary queries.

Here's the query and code that crashes it. How can I make it not?

```
$query =
    "SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SQL_BIG_RESULT
        products.*,
        inventory.*,
        pricing.*,
        markets.*
    FROM
        products,
        categories,
        markets,
        pricing,
        inventory
    WHERE
        products.catid = categories.id AND
        markets.id = products.marketid AND
        pricing.productid = products.id AND
        inventory.productid = products.id AND
        inventory.all_stock > 0 AND
        products.sale = 'Y' AND
        categories.active = 'Y' AND
        inventory.last_update > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    GROUP BY
        products.id";

$Db = new DbConnector();

$r = $Db->query($query); // !Never gets past this point!

while ($product = $r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // Stuff gets done here.
}
```

Comment: Try to limit rows fetched at once.

Comment: you might also want to specify the columns in your select statement rather than using products.*,         inventory.*,
        pricing.*,
        markets.*

Comment: @Maximus2012 I already do. I just snipped them out for brevity's sake in this posting.

Comment: Did you run an `explain` on the above select to see if it can use indexes?

Comment: is the query statement itself slow or is it the fetching part that is crashing the server? Do you have all the proper indices etc. in place? have you used explain select in the raw query statement directly against the database (outside PHP)? if its the fetching/inserting into another database part that is slow and not the query statement itself then you might be better off using an ETL tool like Pentaho PDI/Kettle.

Comment: As @ElonThan mentioned above, limiting the query and then running this script multiple times (while changing the limit clause parameter values each time) might be another solution.

Comment: @Maximus2012 That might be a good way to go.

Comment: @Maerlyn I did, but it wasn't highly useful. Might need to test forcing use of indexes to prevent scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Does the query run on the database server alone? If so the bottleneck is most likely with your web server and it's communications with your database server. If you're pulling huge amounts of data or you are forced to run large numbers of queries (if you have to run additional queries for each id retrieved) I recommend using **STORED PROCEDURES** (mysql calls them "routines").
You can get started here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures/

Comment: This script has a lot of other retrievals for each ID, so I will probably employ this for other parts of the script to see if there is a speed boost. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Coulnd't you just put the id fields into a temp table then "hydrate" and process full rows in batches?

First the temp table with just the ids:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempy
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SQL_BIG_RESULT
    products.id  AS product_id,
    inventory.id AS inventory_id,
    pricing.id   AS pricing_id,
    markets.id   AS markets_id
FROM
    products,
    categories,
    markets,
    pricing,
    inventory
WHERE
    products.catid = categories.id AND
    markets.id = products.marketid AND
    pricing.productid = products.id AND
    inventory.productid = products.id AND
    inventory.all_stock > 0 AND
    products.sale = 'Y' AND
    categories.active = 'Y' AND
    inventory.last_update > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY
    products.id
```

Repeat this query until everything is processed, but in each step increment the OFFSET value:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SQL_BIG_RESULT
    products.*,
    inventory.*,
    pricing.*,
    markets.*
FROM
    ( SELECT *
      FROM tempy
      LIMIT  1000     -- slice size
      OFFSET 1000*123 -- slice number
      ORDER BY whatever.you.want
    ) AS t,
    products,
    inventory,
    pricing,
    markets
WHERE
    products.id  = t.products_id
    inventory.id = t.inventory_id
    pricing.id   = t.pricing_id
    markets.id   = t.markets_id
```

Comment: And this would be faster/less resource intensive?

Comment: I'll give it a shot and let you know then! Thanks!